# The problem is System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#

When i enter numbers like 3, 4 ,6 its ok, but when i enter number like 3,2 3,4. problem appears
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

```
using System.Text;

namespace homework4_2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

            
            Console.Write("введіть число від 0-100: ");
            double ClientNum = (Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

            if (ClientNum <= 14)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Твоє число в діапазоні 0-14");
            }

            else if (ClientNum <= 35 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Твоє число в діапазоні 15-35");
            }

            else if (ClientNum <= 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Твоє число в діапазоні 36-50");
            }
            
            else if (ClientNum <= 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Твоє число в діапазоні 51-100");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("немає діапазона у якому б було твоє число");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Here's a hint: An `int` is **not** a `double`.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` can't convert whatever you are trying to convert to an `int`.  Also why is `ClientNum` a `double` if you are using `Convert.ToInt32`?

Comment: Is there a space between 2 and 3?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. int is not a double, so use either `double.Parse` or `float.Parse` (with float variable type) to parse the input.
2. There is an `IFormatProvider` in `double.Parse`/`float.Parse`, depending on system settings your number will be parsed either with "." or with "," delimiter (like 1.3 or 4,6), so I recommend you to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the second argument to `.Parse` method and replace "." with "," in the input with `.Replace(',', '.')`.

P.S. To questioner: Якщо тобі буде потрібна інша допомога, ти можешь знайти мої контакти на моїй сторінці на гітхаб (дивись посилання у профілі).